# OpenAcc Intel Fortran Compiler

Tags: fortran, openacc

I am trying to compile a code in Fortran using OpenAcc. So far I have been using Intel fortran which supports OpenMP, but apparently does not support OpenAcc. Can anyone suggest a free compiler that supports OpenAcc?

The exact code I am trying to run can be found on [this](http://www.kellogg.northwestern.edu/rc/workshops/mp2.html#sec-6) link, but I am pasting it below as well for convenience:

```
program rbc
use omp_lib     ! For timing
implicit none
real, parameter :: beta = 0.984, eta = 2, alpha = 0.35, delta = 0.01, &
       rho = 0.95, sigma = 0.005, zmin=-0.0480384, zmax=0.0480384;
integer, parameter :: nz = 4, nk=4800;
real :: zgrid(nz), kgrid(nk), t_tran_z(nz,nz), tran_z(nz,nz);
real :: kmax, kmin, tol, dif, c(nk), r(nk), w(nk);
real, dimension(nz,nk) :: v=0., v0=0., ev=0., c0=0.;
integer :: i, iz, ik, cnt;
logical :: ind(nk);
real(kind=8) :: start, finish   ! For timing
real :: tmpmax, c1  

   !$acc region
   !$acc do parallel
    do ik = 1,nk;
       !$acc do parallel
       do iz=1,nz;        
          tmpmax = -huge(0.)
          do i = 1,nk
             c1 = c0(ik,iz) - kgrid(i)
             if(c1<0) exit
             c1 = c1**(1-eta)/(1-eta)+ev(i,iz)
             if(tmpmax<c1) tmpmax = c1
          end do
          v(ik,iz) = tmpmax
       end do
    end do
    !$acc end region
```

Comment: How about [gfortran](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/OpenACC.html)

Comment: I looked into that but I was confused whether I could install it on a windows operative system. And if so, where to find the installer and how to make sure it recognizes the OpenAcc?

Comment: I just searched "gfortran for windows" and found the following [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries) which provides you with binaries to install on windows. Note OpenACC support was first introduced in v5.1 I think, so you'll need to make sure you get a suitably new version (and v6 is supposed to be a much better implementation). You may also need to do some extra setup to the the relevant support libs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will take a look to the link you provided. Any idea on how to setup the relevant libs?

Comment: No idea I'm afraid, hopefully the installer will come with everything needed. If not you might be able to follow instructions provided for `OpenMP`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PGI Community Edition is a free release of PGI Fortran, C, and C++ compilers and tools including OpenACC, OpenMP, and CUDA Fortran for Linux/x86, Linux/OpenPOWER, and macOS. Look here http://www.pgroup.com/products/community.htm.

Answer (score 3):

Right now the only free compiler choice for OpenACC is GNU, but it's support is still incomplete. I suppose you could one of the research compilers, such as OpenUH or OpenARC, but I'm not sure how useful those are in a production environment. If you're affiliated with a university, you can get a free 1 year license (renewable) for PGI though. If you're not, you can still get a free trial to see if it does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The LLVM fortran compiler (Flang) is aiming to support OpenACC. Currently they only support OpenACC parsing for simple "hello-world" type programs, but full support is under active development.

https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/master/flang/